# How to route to a new page in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing

I have three links in Home Page:-

ComponentA ComponentB ComponentC

Now if I click on ComponentA, the output is coming as

****ComponentA ComponentB ComponentC
ComponentA works.****

I want to see the output as ie After Clicking Component A only Component A will be shown

**ComponentA works**

I am new in Angular 8 and only know basics.Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

in your app.cpmponent.html add`<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and remove other components

Comment: This is the code for App.Component,html
<div class="container">
  <a class="nav-link" routerLink="componentA">Component A</a>
  <a routerLink="componentB">Component B</a>

  <a routerLink="componentC">Component C</a>
  </div>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
Not Working by your suggestion

Comment: @PrincePritamGur in app.cpmponent.html put only `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` . Change your router.module.ts for differetn paths

Comment: see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crud-example-with-mock-services?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Ok.. I understand. Thank you